Incorrect rendering of VTK C++ examples on Linux
I'm trying to compile and run VTK examples on my Linux PC.
The main windows of the all C++ examples display random junk instead of shapes and background.
My configuration is:
Linux kernel version:          6.6.47-generic-1rosa2021.1-x86_64
GCC version:                   11.4.0
VTK version:                   9.3.1 (builded from sources)
vtkProbeOpenGLVersion reports: Class: vtkXOpenGLRenderWindow succeeded in finding a working OpenGL
OpenGL vendor string:          Mesa
OpenGL renderer string:        NV126
OpenGL version string:         4.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 23.3.6

A simple OpenGL C++ application built without VTK but only with glew and glfw also renders correctly.
What may be wrong with my PC/Linux configuration or C++ toolchain?
SOLVED. C++ toolchain is OK. The problem was that my driver/GPU combination don`t support MSAA textures. For more information see [VTK 9.0.0] Rendering issue (many artifacts) with Nouveau driver.
VTK merge request that fixes this OpenGLRenderWindow: Disable MSAA on nouveau

C++ toolchain is OK. The problem was that my driver/GPU combination don`t support MSAA textures. For more information see [VTK 9.0.0] Rendering issue (many artifacts) with Nouveau driver.
VTK merge request that fixes this OpenGLRenderWindow: Disable MSAA on nouveau
